# Can anyone tell me what the 'for' line code of this program does, I dont understand the 2nd part of it with the question mark

Tags: for-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main () 
{
    int x, i=2, k=1;

    for (x=15; x%i ? ++i : ++k, 1<x ; x-- , i++)
    {
        x -= k+i;
        i++;
        printf("X = %d , I = %d , K = %d\n",x,i,k);
    } 
    switch(x) {
        case 2: printf("Display 2.\n");
        case 5: printf("Display 5.\n");
        case 0: printf("Display 0.\n");
                break;
        default:
            printf("Display default\n");
    }
system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the 'for' line code of this program does, I dont understand the 2nd part of it with the question mark

Comment: which part ? u can't understand ?

Comment: What is the language and the standard? Need to be careful with sequencing points with x%i ? ++i : ++k

Answer (score 0):

That is the ternary operator.  Google on that for more detail, but basically, if the part to the left of the `?` is true, the whole expression evaluates to the value on the left of the `:`. If the part to the left of the `?` is false, then the whole expression evaluates to the value on the right of the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x%i ?< ++i : ++k
```

means :

```
int iterate(){
    if( x%i == 1 ) {
     return ++i;
    }else{
     return ++k;
    }
}

for (x = 15; iterate() ; 1...)
```

Comment: This was really helpful , I know this sounds stupid (just a beginner here) but what does (x%i) mean in this context.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation ;) modulo is the name for % in the most of the programming languages

Answer (score 0):

```
if (1 == 1){
  they are equal;
} else {
  they are not equal
}

1 == 1 ? they are equal : they are not equal
```

Two examples are same. It's pseudo code. :)

If condition is true, do left side, else do right side.

In your example author put condition in for loop, but logic is the same.

You can read more, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)